# higchart laravel

Tags: laravel, highcharts

Hola como podría realizar un gráfico con highchart en laravel de tal forma que yo seleccione el rango de fecha me muestre el registro mensual de las computadoras que tengo en mi base de datos,porque lo trate de hacer pero cuando coloco las fecha y doy submit me sale el siguiente error :The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD.

En mi vista:

```
        <h3 class="index">Estadísticas del año</h3>
<form class="col-md-12" method="post" action="{{url('/estAnual')}}" >
        @csrf
    <div class="form-group">
        <input class="col-sm-4" type="date" id="fechainicio" placeholder="fechainicio">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input class="col-sm-4" type="date" id="fechafin" placeholder="fechafin">
    </div>
    <input class="btn btn-info" type="submit" value="Agregar">
</form>
   <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center ">
        <div class="col-md-4">

            {!! $chart->container() !!}
            {!! $chart->script() !!}
        </div>
   </div>
```

En mi controlador:

```
 public function reg_anual(Request $request){

  $fechainicio= $request->get('fechainicio');
    $fechafin= $request->get('fechafin');

    $Enero= Computadora::whereBetween('created_at', [$fechainicio,$fechafin])->count();
    $Febrero= Computadora::whereBetween('created_at', [$fechainicio,$fechafin])->count();
    $Marzo= Computadora::whereBetween('created_at', [$fechainicio,$fechafin])->count();
    $Abril= Computadora::whereBetween('created_at', [$fechainicio,$fechafin])->count();
    $Mayo= Computadora::whereBetween('created_at', [$fechainicio,$fechafin])->count();
    $Junio= Computadora::whereBetween('created_at', [$fechainicio,$fechafin])->count();
    $Julio= Computadora::whereBetween('created_at', [$fechainicio,$fechafin])->count();
    $Agosto= Computadora::whereBetween('created_at', [$fechainicio,$fechafin])->count();
    $Septiembre= Computadora::whereBetween('created_at', [$fechainicio,$fechafin])->count();
    $Octubre= Computadora::whereBetween('created_at', [$fechainicio,$fechafin])->count();
    $Noviembre = Computadora::whereBetween('created_at', [$fechainicio,$fechafin])->count();
    $Diciembre = Computadora::whereBetween('created_at', [$fechainicio,$fechafin])->count();
        $chart = new ComputChart();
        $chart->labels(['Ene', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Abr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Agos', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dic']);
        $chart->dataset('Computadoras registradas en 2019', 'line', [$Enero, $Febrero, $Marzo, $Abril, $Mayo, $Junio, $Julio, $Agosto, $Septiembre, $Octubre, $Noviembre, $Diciembre])->color('green')
            ->backgroundColor('#90EE90');

    return view('grafica/anual',compact('chart'));


}
```

En las rutas:

```
Route::get('/estAnual', 'GraficasController@reg_anual');
```

Comment: ¿Probaste cambiar el method del form a GET?

Comment: Si lo probé pero entonces me sale The GETmethod is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST, HEAD.Alguien me pdría decir como hacerlo con AJAX o con Javascript, para que me muestre el grafrico a partir de un rango de fechas